# A world with (some) telepaths

Tags: telepathy

Could a telepath make another (non-telepathic person) appear to have telepathy?

It would seem to require the telepath to not only read someone's thoughts, but also WRITE thoughts to a person as well.  I don't know if there is another term for this capability.

Comment: What are your requirements for telepathy? Can these telepaths only read thoughts? Technology? Please elaborate.

Comment: If you are asking for English term for writing thoughts, then this is quite off topic here, belongs to English Stack Exchange. If you are asking if in your world telepathy works that way, then currently only answer is "if you want it to".

Comment: Also, this may be helpful: the thought-sending is called brain-messaging https://askabiologist.asu.edu/plosable/brain-messaging

Answer (score 2):

Some people experience this "written thoughts" thing as actually happening.  It is called [thought insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_insertion) and it is a symptom of schizophrenia.

> The subject has thoughts that she thinks are the thoughts of other
>   people, somehow occurring in her own mind. It is not that the subject
>   thinks that other people are making her think certain thoughts as if
>   by hypnosis or psychokinesis, but that other people think the thoughts
>   using the subject's mind as a psychological medium.

This can be a pretty unsettling thing if you do not know where the thoughts are coming from, especially if the thoughts themselves are of violent and disturbing things.  But if you were ready to receive thoughts (for example you are aware that your telepath associate is going to send you what you need) it could work well, especially if you could readily identify the inserted thoughts when they arrived.